# Low Seg2Cat and category image

Tags: categories, low-seg2cat

I'm trying to pull a category image using `segment_n_category_image` variable from Low Seg2Cat add-on.

Code looks like:

```
<img src="{segment_2_category_image}" alt="{segment_2_category_name}" class="img-responsive img-ctr">
```

and output:

```
<img class="img-responsive img-ctr" alt="XYZ Category Title" src="{filedir_1}xyz_image.jpg">
```

It looks fine except `{filerdir_1}` part which I have no clue where comes from.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Low Seg2Cat deliberately doesn't parse the file paths in the category image for performance reasons.

You can use the [Parse File Paths](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/parse-file-paths) add-on to get those parsed.

Comment: Also found that topic: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9975/low-seg2cat-and-category-images-file-path-doesnt-resolve